# File dialogs crash when compiling with static version of Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, static-linking

I have a Rust project with a C++ Qt front-end. I compiled the Linux version on Mint 19 with a static version of Qt . I was informed (https://github.com/spieglt/Cloaker/issues/2) that the file dialog crashes when selecting `Computer` in the left sidebar or typing `/` as a path. I found that the file dialog I see when using the static version of Qt (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVqvu.jpg) is different from the one I see when compiling with the standard, dynamically linked version (https://i.stack.imgur.com/anScJ.jpg) made by the Qt installer.

The output on the user's machine was:

```
./Cloaker.run 
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion
Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried compiling with a static version of Qt on Ubuntu. When I do that, the program doesn't crash when the broken file dialog appears, but `Computer` is the only item in the side and top bars not greyed out, and the output is

```
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    QPixmap::scaleWidth: Pixmap is a null pixmap
    Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Empty filename passed to function
    QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
    QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
    QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
    Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
    Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collation implementation
```

Original Mint configure command: 
`~/Qt/5.12.3/Src/configure -prefix ~/qt-static/5.12.3 -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -skip multimedia -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-openssl -no-libpng -skip wayland -qt-xcb`

Ubuntu configure command: 
`~/Qt/5.13.0/Src/configure -static -release -prefix ~/qt-static/install -opensource -confirm-license -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-openssl -no-libpng -fontconfig`

File dialog code:

```
    if (mode == Encrypt) { // encrypt, append extension
        inFile += QString::fromUtf8(FILE_EXTENSION);
        return QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save encrypted file", inFile, "", nullptr, QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite);
    } else { // decrypt, chop off extension if there, otherwise prepend decrypted.
        if (inFile.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
            inFile = inFile.left(inFile.length() - strlen(FILE_EXTENSION));
        } else {
            inFile += QString::fromUtf8("_decrypted");
        }
        // save as dialog, return path
        return QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save decrypted file", inFile, "", nullptr, QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite);
    }
```

I would like to, if possible, get the normal GNOME file dialog when linking Qt statically. If this isn't possible, will AppImage have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had just built the static version of Qt incorrectly. To build a static Qt with working file dialogs (Qt Widgets, QFileDialog-style; not GTK-style) on Mint:

```
$ mkdir ~/qt-static && cd ~/qt-static
$ mkdir build install; cd build
$ ~/Qt/5.12.3/Src/configure -prefix ~/qt-static/install -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -skip multimedia -skip webengine -skip wayland -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-openssl -ico -gtk -gif -qt-xcb
$ make -j8
```

Ubuntu is the same except without `-qt-xcb` and with `-fontconfig`.